# Cloud Run container working for some time, then failing with authorization error

Tags: google-cloud-functions, authorization, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

The GCP project includes a pipeline to scrape a particular website every minute. The Cloud Scheduler is set to fire every minute, and post a request to a Cloud function, which then calls the Cloud Run container I'm having issues with. The Cloud Scheduler and Function work properly, and submit requests every minute. The Cloud Run, on the other hand, scrapes successfully for some time, and then suddenly starts posting this message:

```
The request was not authorized to invoke this service. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating
```

I am not sure why the authorization to make requests would be suddenly revoked after some successful scrapes. Is there some limit on how much I can call a Run container each day? Or could this be due to something else? Any help is appreciated, and if more info is needed, I'll add it. Thanks!

EDIT: I still seem to have this problem, and I'm unsure what to do with it. I thought it was a permission issue, but fiddling around with the IAM permissions didn't work. This also doesn't seem to be a prevalent issue, from my efforts to Google it.

Comment: How long is **for some time**?

Comment: Can you clarify if that error is coming from the Cloud Run logs or the Cloud Functions logs? That error indicates that the service account you are using for executing Cloud Functions has lost access, possibly because of an invalid Bearer Token

Comment: It worked successfully for around 3 hours, scraping every minute, until it started the showing the authorization error. The error is coming from the Cloud Run logs. The Cloud functions log does not show any abnormal behavior.

Comment: Do you see errors in Cloud Scheduler or Cloud Functions logs which invoke your Cloud Run (such as a 403 or 401 error type)?

Comment: There are no errors in the Function or Scheduler logs, only messages saying that the requests have been passed along, and they finished with status "ok". The only anomaly is with the Cloud Run logs.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue ?

Comment: Yes I am, unfortunately. I'm not sure how I would go about making this question active again (other than posting a copy, but I don't think that's allowed).

Comment: is your cloud run service public ?

Comment: The project is for a company, so it's not public.

Comment: @p_mo did you make any changes to the project recently (eg. delete any Service Account)?

Comment: I have a similar issue, I setup service to service authentication on 2 cloud-run services and initially,requests get authenticated as expected but after some time (Like a day). I start getting authentication errors until I redeploy the requesting service.