# Cloud Run container not running due to permission issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

The GCP project includes a pipeline to scrape a particular website every minute. The Cloud Scheduler is set to fire every minute, and post a request to a Cloud function, which then calls the Cloud Run container I'm having issues with. The Cloud Scheduler and Function work properly, and submit requests every minute, and their logs don't show any errors.

The Cloud Run container, however, returns this message every time the scrape is run:

```
The request was not authorized to invoke this service. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating
```

How do I go about fixing this error? I think it has something to do with the the Cloud Function not being authorized to call the Run container, but I'm not sure what to do about this. I'll add more info if needed.
Thanks!

Note: This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68901139/cloud-run-container-working-for-some-time-then-failing-with-authorization-error) one I posted some time back. However, the difference now is that the container starts throwing these errors immediately, whereas before, it would run for a bit before failing.

Comment: what does the authentication setting show for Cloud Run service and what permissions you have attached to Cloud Function service account?

Comment: Cloud Scheduler can directly invoke Cloud Run. Unless Cloud Functions is also providing additional value, remove that service.

Comment: @Asdfg I have allowed all traffic and require authentication with IAM. Do you know which service email corresponds to Cloud Functions?

Comment: @JohnHanley I will try removing the Cloud Function, but I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: If you are asking what service email corresponds to Cloud Functions, You need to do some basic reading on how things work. This will save you lots of time and hassle.

Answer (score 0):

The isue might be related to the permissions of the service account associated to the Cloud Function. In order to solve it, you can try the following steps:

- Check the service account associated with the Cloud Function.
- Grant this service account with the Cloud Run Invoker role (`roles/run.invoker`) in your Cloud Run service.
- Follow the [authentication process](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#run-service-to-service-example-python) inside your Cloud Function before making the request to the Cloud Run service URL. One option is to [use the metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#use_the_metadata_server) to get the ID token, and include this token in the headers of the request to the Cloud Run service.

Another option would be to make your Cloud Run service **public** by adding the Cloud Run Invoker role to the `allUsers` member type. Bare in mind that **this will allow unauthenticated invocations**, so the Cloud Function will be able to make the request to the service.

Comment: Adding this code didn't make it work. Is there some error with this?

Comment: Check the SA associated to the CF, grant the SA with the invoker role in the Cloud Run service and then proceed with the authentication. Once this is done, a way of doing the authentication is to retrieve de ID token through the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#use_the_metadata_server) and then include this token in the request as in [this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/developers#testing) documentation, but changing the `$(gcloud auth print-identity-token)` with the token you obtained before. Have you tried this approach?